# How do I sort my javascript array by its element which are nested inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is my array:

```
var myarray=[
       ["abc",1,**3**],
       ["def",2,**1**],
       ["ijh",0,**5**],
       ["abc",0,**5**]
];
```

Now i want to **Sort the Array** on the basis of values at the second element of each position. Have a look at the position of the highlight values.

How can i do it?

Comment: myarray.sort works only if i have the single values at each location.

Comment: Can you please share your expected sorting result?

Comment: what is the "*second*" element?

Comment: why can't you just hard code it. Accessing the second element and then plugging it in the sorting algorithm of your like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try this code at my end it's working fine, Please try this one

```
var myarray=[
       ["abc",1,'**3**'],
       ["def",2,'**1**'],
       ["ijh",0,'**5**'],
       ["abc",0,'**5**']
];
console.log(myarray);

myarray.sort(function(a, b){
 return b[1]-a[1]
})

console.log(myarray);
```

You can see the example here https://jsfiddle.net/ob5cd4fh/

Comment: This is not an answer .... user does not want sorting based on 2nd element.. plus is there any difference between your answer and @rafael answer ?..... the difference whic is there is what user does not want

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a basic bubble sort algorithm?

```
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {  
    if (myarray[i][1] > myarray[i+1][1]) {                         
        var tmp = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = myarray[i+1];
        myarray[i+1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have it sorted in ascending order, define a comparison function like the following

```
myarray.sort(function (item1, item2) { return item1[2] - item2[2]; });
```

Comment: this works if and only if i have only one value at each location.

Comment: the above code results in myarray sorted `[ ["def",2,1], ["abc",1,3], ["ijh",0,5], ["abc",0,5] ]` (so, first goes array with 1 at the end, then one with 3, then both with 5 at last index) . If it's not the expected result, then please show your expected result, so I will be able to adjust my code accordingly.